# How to get drive letter of a USB memory stick drive given its volume label?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2

A USB memory stick has two partitions - one read only and the other read-write.

My program runs from the read-only partition.

The volume labels for both partitions are fixed by the manufacturer: 
MYDISK-RO and MYDISK-RW

When inserted in Windows, each partition (volume) gets a different drive letter. These drive letters are different on different computers depending on the configuration ie. the number of drive letters already allocated to disk drives.

My question is:

Which is the best (most efficient) way for the program to find the drive letter of the read-write partition, using the volume label?

It needs to work on Windows XP and up.

Rather than enumerate all drive letters and compare the volume label to the one that we need, I'm looking ideally for a single function call to Windows .. something like:

GetDriveLetterByVolumeName(AVolumeLabel: String);

or

GetVolumeInformation(AVolumeLabel: String);

Is there such a function or is enumerating the drive letters and comparing each volume label the only solution?

TIA.

Comment: 1) Define "efficient". 2) If there are "a number of Windows API functions", certainly you could at least have tried one or two and could mention (and benchmark) them, right? Vaguely mentioning you know something exists without showing any effort does not count as effort.

Comment: @KenWhite: I only know that there are WinAPI functions by seeing other posts on SO, but I did not try them. Hence that is why I posted this question.

Comment: My question then would be why not? It seems that *anything* that worked would be better than **nothing**, and then you can worry about whether or not it's efficient. Note that there's a problem with your idea anyway-it's entirely possible to have multiple drives with the same volume name, even if they're both removable drives. Just try inserting two of your memory sticks in separate USB ports at the same time, and you'll see four drive letters, two with each partition name. How do you tell which is paired with the one you need?

Comment: @KenWhite: If that is the case, I would like the first one that matches the volume label. Any solution?

Comment: Chances are what you already have best solution. What did you try?

Comment: I've edited my question to be more clear about what I need to achieve.

Comment: The corect approach for solving your problem would be to first enumerate all removable devices (flash drives, removable HDD's, memory cards etc.). Once you have this you check which drive letters were assigned to specific device so you get similary sorted information as it is displayed when you left click on "Safetly remove device" icon in the Taskbar. Unfortunately I don't know which API calls do you need to achieve this. SO I hope I athleast guded you toward the right direction.

Comment: The "right" way is to get the current drive and enumerate the volumes of that drive, only then you are sure to have the right volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long long time ago I used this code (Was on Delphi7)
This procedure add in combobox all the root of all Removable drives found

```
Procedure TfMain.GetDiskDrives();
var
  r: LongWord;
  Drives: array[0..128] of char;
  pDrive: pchar;
begin
  Result := '';
  r := GetLogicalDriveStrings(sizeof(Drives), Drives);
  if r = 0 then exit;
  if r > sizeof(Drives) then
    raise Exception.Create(SysErrorMessage(ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY));
  pDrive := Drives;  // Point to the first drive
  while pDrive^ <> #0 do begin
    if GetDriveType(pDrive) = DRIVE_REMOVABLE then begin
       cDrive.Items.Add(pDrive);
    end;
    inc(pDrive, 4);  // Point to the next drive
  end;
  if cDrive.Items.Count=1 then cDrive.ItemIndex:=0;
end;
```

After that you can use the following function to get the volume name

```
function GetVolumeName(DriveLetter: Char): string;
var
  dummy: DWORD;
  buffer: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  oldmode: LongInt;
begin
  oldmode := SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
  try
    GetVolumeInformation(PChar(DriveLetter + ':\'),
                         buffer,
                         SizeOf(buffer),
                         nil,
                         dummy,
                         dummy,
                         nil,
                         0);
    Result := StrPas(buffer);
  finally
    SetErrorMode(oldmode);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer compared to the other people who passed useless, time-wasting comments to my question. In fact this answer works and although my question was about whether there is a more direct approach (ie single function call to the Windows API to get the drive letter given the volume label), I will still use this code.

Answer (score -1):

I'm posting my code adapted from Gianluca Colombo's answer:

Tested and working with Delphi XE2 Update 4.1 on Windows 7 x64.

```
unit uDiskUtils;

interface

uses Windows, Classes, SysUtils;

Procedure GetDiskDrives(var ADriveList: TStrings);
function GetVolumeName(const ADriveLetter: Char): string;
function FindDiskDriveByVolumeName(const AVolumeName: String): Char;

implementation

Procedure GetDiskDrives(var ADriveList: TStrings);
var
  r: LongWord;
  Drives: array [0 .. 128] of Char;
  pDrive: pchar;
begin

  ADriveList.Clear;

  r := GetLogicalDriveStrings(sizeof(Drives), Drives);
  if r = 0 then
    exit;
  if r > sizeof(Drives) then
    raise Exception.Create(SysErrorMessage(ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY));
  pDrive := Drives; // Point to the first drive
  while pDrive^ <> #0 do
  begin
    if GetDriveType(pDrive) = DRIVE_REMOVABLE then
    begin
      ADriveList.Add(pDrive);
    end;
    inc(pDrive, 4); // Point to the next drive
  end;
end;

function GetVolumeName(const ADriveLetter: Char): string;
var
  dummy: DWORD;
  buffer: array [0 .. MAX_PATH] of Char;
  oldmode: LongInt;
begin
  oldmode := SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
  try
    GetVolumeInformation(pchar(ADriveLetter + ':\'), buffer, sizeof(buffer), nil, dummy, dummy, nil, 0);
    Result := StrPas(buffer);
  finally
    SetErrorMode(oldmode);
  end;
end;

function FindDiskDriveByVolumeName(const AVolumeName: String): Char;
var
  dl: TStringList;
  c: Integer;
begin
  Result := ' ';

  dl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    GetDiskDrives(TStrings(dl));

    for c := 0 to dl.Count - 1 do
      if (AVolumeName = GetVolumeName(dl[c][1])) then
        Result := dl[c][1];

  finally
    dl.Free;
  end;

end;

end.
```